# RemoteAction in Promise doesn't work at all. no request receiving - in visualforce page

Tags: javascript, promise, salesforce, jspdf, visualforce

I use jspdf lib and some kind of lib that converting dom element into image(dom-to-image), because jspdf setfont is not properly working. (Korean lang is not encoded or working in fonts)

First I convert DOM element into image, and I put that image into pdf by jspdf, after that I get the datauri from jspdf. I confirmed uri was properly made, but remote action is not working. only shows empty white page

-----javascript in visualforce page

```
    var quoteId = '{!Quote.Id}';
    
    function saveDOM() {
        if (domtoimage) {
            var node = document.getElementById('DomElement');
            var promises = [];

            promises.push(domtoimage.toPng(node, {quality : 1.0, bgcolor : '#fff', width : 950}));
            Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
                var dataUrl = results[0];

                if(quoteId, dataUrl) {
                    var attBody = dataUrl.split(',')[1];
                    
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
                        window.html2canvas = html2canvas;

                        var doc = new jsPDF();
                        doc.addImage(attBody, 'PNG', 1, 10, 200, Math.floor(node.offsetHeight/4.7));

                        resolve(doc.output('datauri'));

                    }).then((result) => {
                        if(result){
                            var pdfBody = result.split(',')[1];
                            
                            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                                '{!$RemoteAction.SaveAsPdfExtension.savePDF}',
                                pdfBody, quoteId,
                                function(result, event) {
                                    if(event.status && result) {
                                        alert('success!');
                                        window.location.href = '/' + quoteId;
                                    } else {
                                        alert('Something went wrong, please refresh the page.');
                                    }
                                }
                            );



                        }
                    })
                }
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
            });
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong, please refresh the page.');
        }
    }
```

-------------------apex controller

```
@RemoteAction
global static Boolean savePDF(String body, String parentId) {

    QuoteDocument qd = new QuoteDocument(); 
    
    qd.Document = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(body);
    qd.QuoteId = parentId;

    Database.SaveResult res = Database.insert(qd);

    return res.isSuccess();
}
```

I don't know why requests are not received in controller.
if use jspdf.save() instead of output('datauri') and not request to the controller, it works properly.(download pdf document and it's perfect)
or pass the step that put image on pdf and just send image uri to controller, then it works properly too. (image is uploaded in attachment, and it's perfect too - when I change the apex code into making attachment)
but when it comes to combine these two steps together, controller never receives any requests.

please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I figured it out. This was because that converted datauri length was too long, so I needed to use action Function

Comment: Have you experimented with jspdf's `setFont` (https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF)? It's been few years ago and I needed Japanese rather than Korean but I vaguely remember I found a royalty-free font "Senobi Gothic", converted ttf to JS, added that to static resource, `<apex:includeScript`ed it after jspdf and turned out pretty good